# Django rest framework cannot deal with multiple objects in model viewset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very simple model and its related serializer and views:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'pub_date')

class PageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer
```

Now I can post like this:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "title": "Lorem ipsum"
}
```

This works fine. But I would like to post multiple objects like this:

```
[
    {
        "user": 1,
        "title": "Lorem ipsum one"
    },
    {
        "user": 1,
        "title": "Lorem ipsum two"
    }
]
```

But this gives me an error:

> "non_field_errors": [
>
> ```
> "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."
> ```
>
> ]

So to accept multiple objects I modified the view [as per the doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects):

```
class PageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Page.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PageSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

But I am getting an error:

> TypeError at /api/blog/pages/
>
> 'ListSerializer' object is not callable

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You had it set up correctly before, the serializer_class should point to the class like this:

```
serializer_class = PageSerializer
```

You were right on the error, it doesn't like receiving multiple objects in the POST. One way to fix it would be to override the get_serializer method n the view, adding in many=True there.

Something like:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if "data" in kwargs:
        data = kwargs["data"]

        # check if many is required
        if isinstance(data, list):
            kwargs["many"] = True

    return super(PageViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

To answer your question in the comments: `isinstance()` is a Python method to check the type of an object. In this case, it's a `list` when passing in multiple objects, so we just check what type `data` is and set `many=true` if it's a `list`.

[DRF docs regarding get_serializer (under methods)](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview)

[Python docs regarding isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

Comment: Woah... Thank you. I didn't show any docs on `isinstance()` method. Could you maybe point me where it is, or maybe elaborate how to use `isinstance()` please.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. I've updated my answer to provide more info on that.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do this

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    many = True if isinstance(request.data, list) else False
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=many)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors,
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```