# django: Assertion Error `create()` did not return an object instance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I am using Django Rest Framework. I have an existing database (cannot make any changes to it). I have defined a serializer - ReceiptLog with no model, which should create entries in TestCaseCommandRun and TestCaseCommandRunResults when a post() request is made to ReceiptLog api endpoint. Receipt log doesn't exist in the database, I am using it just as an endpoint to accept a combined payload and create entries in underlying tables. Post() to TestCaseCommandRunResults and TestCaseCommandRun works independently, however, when I try to post through ReceiptLog it throws below error

Error Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py" in inner
  52.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in post
  192.         return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  21.         self.perform_create(serializer)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in perform_create
  26.         serializer.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  216.                 '`create()` did not return an object instance.'

Exception Type: AssertionError at /dqf_api/ReceiptLog/
Exception Value: `create()` did not return an object instance.
```

models.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRun(models.Model):
   # fields ..Doesn't have id field as the database doesn't have it
   class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'test_case_command_run'
      unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name', 'suite_run_id', 'case_name', 'command_name'),)


class TestCaseCommandRunResults(models.Model):
    # fields ..Doesn't have id field as the database doesn't have it
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_case_command_run_results'
        unique_together = (('suite_run_id', 'command_run_id', 'rule_name', 'result_id'),)
```

views.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRunViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet.objects.values('team_name','suite_name','suite_run_id', 'case_name','command_name','command_run_id','run_start','run_end','result','run_status')
    serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet

class TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet.objects.values('suite_run_id','command_run_id','rule_name', 'result_id',
                                                           'result','expected_values','actual_values','report_values','extended_values')
    serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet

class ReceiptLogViewSet(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ReceiptLogSerializer.ReceiptLogSerializerClass
```

serializers.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet
        fields = ['suite_run_id','command_run_id','rule_name', 'result_id','result','expected_values','actual_values','report_values','extended_values']

class TestCaseCommandRunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestCaseCommandRunSerializer
        fields = ['team_name','suite_name','suite_run_id', 'case_name','command_name','command_run_id','run_start','run_end','result','run_status']

class ReceiptLogSerializerClass(serializers.Serializer):
    team_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    suite_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    suite_run_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=False, allow_blank=True, default=datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    case_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    command_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    command_run_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=False, allow_blank=True, default='Not Applicable')
    run_start = serializers.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=False)
    run_end = serializers.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=False)
    result = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, default='Not Applicable')
    run_status = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
    rule_name = serializers.CharField( max_length=50, required=False, allow_blank=True,  default='Not Applicable')
    expected_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)
    actual_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)
    report_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)
    extended_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
    # command_run_data_list = []
    command_run_results_data_list = []
    raw_data_list = []
    many = isinstance(validated_data, list)
    if many:
        raw_data_list = validated_data
    else:
        raw_data_list.append(validated_data)
    result_id = 1
    for data_row in raw_data_list:
        new_command_run_entry = {
            'team_name': data_row.get('team_name'),
            'suite_name': data_row.get('suite_name'),
            'suite_run_id': data_row.get('suite_run_id'),
            'case_name': data_row.get('case_name'),
            'command_name': data_row.get('command_name'),
            'command_run_id': data_row.get('command_run_id'),
            'run_start': data_row.get('run_start'),
            'run_end': data_row.get('run_end'),
            'result': data_row.get('result'),
            'run_status': data_row.get('run_status')
        }
        command_run_data_list.append(new_command_run_entry)
        new_command_run_result_entry = {
            'suite_run_id': data_row.get('suite_run_id'),
            'command_run_id': data_row.get('command_run_id'),
            'rule_name': data_row.get('rule_name'),
            'result_id': result_id,
            'result': data_row.get('result'),  # PASS or FAIL
            'expected_values': data_row.get('expected_values'),
            'actual_values': data_row.get('actual_values'),
            'report_values': data_row.get('report_values'),
            'extended_values': data_row.get('extended_values'),
        }
        command_run_results_data_list.append(new_command_run_result_entry)
        result_id += 1

    for item in command_run_results_data_list:
        response_run_results = models.TestCaseCommandRunResults.objects.create(**item)

    for item in command_run_data_list:
        response_run = models.TestCaseCommandRun.objects.create(**item)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'test_case_command_runs', views.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet)
router.register(r'test_case_command_run_results', views.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^buildInfo', views.build_info),
    url(r'^isActive', views.is_active),
    url(r'^dqf_api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^dqf_api/ReceiptLog/', views.ReceiptLogView.ReceiptLogViewSet.as_view(), name='ReceiptLog')]
```

Any help is really appreciated.I am new to Django and DRF

Answer (score 4):

Your serializer's `create` method MUST return an instance of the object it represents. Also, you should not iterate inside the serializer to create instances, that should be done on the view: you iterate through the data, calling the serializer each iteration.

Comment: Also, one hint: your code legibility is very poor. Enforce pep8 style guide, it is very hard to read those long lines.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback..I will try to enforce pep8 guidelines.
Also, could you please help understand why should we not iterate serializer and use views? For my current code, since I am using one API end point (ReceiptLog) to create data in two tables, I should use CreateAPIView in the ReceiptLogViews to iterate over the serializers of two tables I wish to post() data to? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you did in there. You are using two different models on the same serializer. Otherwise, just setting the flag `many=True` would do the trick. Why  just not write a second serializer?

Comment: yes I am using two models on same serializer. These two models have their own serializers as well. But as mentioned, I need a single API end point to post() data to these two models. Hence, this design.

Comment: Updated my code - ReceiptLogSerializers.py to include below line
response = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsModel.objects.create(**new_command_run_result_entry)

Comment: However, since I have some additional fields like 'team_name','case_name' and so on in my serializers which are not present in TestCaseCommandRunResults model, it throws below error: -----Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `team_name` on serializer `ReceiptLogSerializerClass`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `TestCaseCommandRunResultsModel` instance.
Original exception text was: 'TestCaseCommandRunResultsModel' object has no attribute 'team_name'.

Answer (score 1):

Updated the serializers.py file to include the below code

```
class ReceiptLogSerializerClass(serializers.Serializer):
    #Fields
    def create(self, validated_data):
        raw_data_list = []
        many = isinstance(validated_data, list)
        if many:
            raw_data_list = validated_data
        else:
            raw_data_list.append(validated_data)
        result_id = 1
        for data_row in raw_data_list:
            new_command_run_entry = {
            'team_name': data_row.get('team_name'),
            'suite_name': data_row.get('suite_name'),
            'suite_run_id': data_row.get('suite_run_id'),
            'case_name': data_row.get('case_name'),
            'command_name': data_row.get('command_name'),
            'command_run_id': data_row.get('command_run_id'),
            'run_start': data_row.get('run_start'),
            'run_end': data_row.get('run_end'),
            'result': data_row.get('result'),
            'run_status': data_row.get('run_status')
        }
       response = TestCaseCommandRunSerializer.create(TestCaseCommandRunSerializer(),validated_data= new_command_run_entry)
       new_command_run_result_entry = {
            'suite_run_id': data_row.get('suite_run_id'),
            'command_run_id': data_row.get('command_run_id'),
            'rule_name': data_row.get('rule_name'),
            'result_id': result_id,
            'result': data_row.get('result'),  # PASS or FAIL
            'expected_values': data_row.get('expected_values'),
            'actual_values': data_row.get('actual_values'),
            'report_values': data_row.get('report_values'),
            'extended_values': data_row.get('extended_values'),
        }
        response = TestCaseCommandRunResultsSerializer.create(TestCaseCommandRunResultsSerializer(),validated_data= new_command_run_result_entry)
        logger.info(" new_command_run_result_entry response %s" % response)
        result_id += 1
    return validated_data
```

I was not de-serializing the data correctly and hence ran into multiple issues. 
        return validated_data
rectified all the errors and now I am able to post() data to multiple models through single API.

For posting a multiple payloads in a single API Call added below lines in ReceiptLogViewSet

```
    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "data" in kwargs:
            data = kwargs["data"]
        if isinstance(data, list):
            kwargs["many"] = True
    return super(ReceiptLogViewSet, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

Ref: [Django rest framework cannot deal with multple objects in model viewset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43525860/django-rest-framework-cannot-deal-with-multple-objects-in-model-viewset)

Answer (score 0):

The serializer ReceiptLogSerializerClass MUST be a **ModelSerializer**, not a Serializer

Answer (score 0):

if you written your own model manager for default user model then there are chances of your method not returning the user instance which should be return.
for example:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_kwargs):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("email should be present")
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_kwargs)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_kwargs):
        extra_kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        #self._create_user(email, password, **extra_kwargs) if this method not returning user instance upon creation this will cause problem `create()` did not return an object instance
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_kwargs)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_kwargs):
        extra_kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        #self._create_user(email, password, **extra_kwargs) if this method not returning user instance upon creation this will cause problem `create()` did not return an object instance
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_kwargs)
```